# How to remove element using jQuery called from a button inside span tags integrated with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble trying to understand why the jQuery function is not called when my button is inside *span* tags.

When I remove the `<span class="input-group-btn">` it works fine, but I need it to comly with the layout.

html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Teste de Adicionar e Remover elementos</h3>
</div>    
<div class="panel-body">
    <form id="inserir_pessoas" method="POST" action="<?=base_url('cadastro/pessoa_fisica/salvar'); ?>">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <label for="telefone">Telefone(s)</label>
                    <div id="telefone" class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <select id="sel_tipo_telefone" class="btn btn-default" name="tipo_telefone[]">
                               <option value="1">Celular</option>
                               <option value="1">Residencial</option>
                               <option value="1">Trabalho</option>
                               <option value="1">Outro</option>
                            </select>
                        </span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="(11) 5555-5555" name="telefone[]">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onClick="delete_obj(this)">X</button>
                        </span>                            
                    </div>
                    <span id="novo_telefone"></span>
                    <p>
                    <button type="button" onClick="clone_obj('telefone', 'novo_telefone')">Novo Telefone</button>                        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>    
</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function clone_obj(obj_name, obj_destination) {
    $('#' + obj_name).clone().appendTo('#' + obj_destination);
}

function delete_obj(obj_name) {    
    $(obj_name).parents('#telefone').remove();
}
```

Any suggestions?

> Question fixed! Thanks

Comment: which function not work? clone or delete or both?

Comment: Try getting rid of class="input-group-btn". Generally this is used to combine two or more elements together perhaps it is messing with the button since there are no other elements in the span.

Comment: are you duplicating ID's when you clone?

Comment: Why do you have the Function Closure in clone_obj?

Comment: @JacobFinamore - he _is_ combining elements together

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef The delete funcion does not work...

Comment: @JacobFinamore This is needed to comply with the layout requested.

Comment: @NormanSchütt Questions edited!

Comment: @Ted yes! Dupplicating them!

Comment: That would break it. Use classes, not ID's. Only one instance of an ID should exist in the dom at a time.

Comment: you sure that your button you want to delete has .parent('#telefone')??

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef yes Sir. it does.

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef I think I got the solution... =| I should I do? Remove the question? should be "parents" or "closest" and not "parent".

Comment: you can use closest , Good Luck :)